# How can I call a method of a parent activity in a thread of a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, multithreading

To give you some context:

I have an activity that has a custom surface view that is created.  This surfaceview has a thread that runs a game.  If the user loses during the game, I want to invoke a `lose()` method that is defined within the activity in which the surfaceview was instantiated.

How would I go about doing that?

So far I have this:

```
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)context
```

and then within the thread in the surfaceview I call:

```
activity.lose()
```

But I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I understand that this call is on a separate thread than a listener in the activity, but how can I notify this activity that a user has lost the game?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: seems to be the Broadcast Receiver way, tried that?

Answer (score 0):

may be your lose() method call something which touch UI operation ,show it

whill throw this Error.

You can resolve it with :

```
Looper.prepare();
activity.close();
```